# Get current location in Xamarin Droid

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm working on map now I want to get current location coordinates in Xamarin android. How can I get coordinates for the current location?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Crossplatform [Geolocator](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/geolocatorplugin) plugin which is developed by jamesmontemagno.

Get coordinates as:

```
var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;
var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync (timeoutMilliseconds: 10000);

Console.WriteLine ("Position Latitude: {0}", position.Latitude);
Console.WriteLine ("Position Longitude: {0}", position.Longitude);
```

Comment: What is `locator` in this sample?